# Convert SQL operator in to Hive QL

Tags: hive, hiveql

I need convert this sql to hive ql. I find the `hive` don't have operator `in` .

```
select type,sum(cost) as Cost from TableName 
WHERE trans_id in (SELECT trans_id FROM TableName WHERE type=0)
group by type;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write it as a LEFT SEMI JOIN:

```
select type,sum(cost) as Cost from T1
LEFT SEMI JOIN T2 ON T1.trans_id = T2.trans_id
WHERE type=0
group by type;
```

As with Hive 0.13 you won't have to do this as [Hive 0.13 supports IN/EXISTS clause with subqueries](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries) ([HIVE-784](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-784)).

Comment: I have taken a almost same workaround to solve that problem. Thanks all the same!